# what is the symbol that looks like space, but not a space? (not a &nbsp;)

Tags: php, html, special-characters, symbols

I'm talking NOT about `&nbsp;` but about another symbol " " that looks like " " even in text area, but that's another symbol (splitting the string by space symbol does NOT split "hello world" into two words).

Comment: @SenorAmor It generates a &nbsp;

Comment: Alt + 160 produces the no-break space, same as `&nbsp;` produces in HTML.

Comment: Why don't you copy-paste exactly what a `print_r` gives you?

Comment: &#160; is a space. I recommend you take a look to the Character Map in Windows

Comment: If you isolate the character call ord($c) on it and that'll tell you what the ascii value is.

Comment: Dr.Kameleon, I put that symbol, that looks like a space into the question.

Comment: Thanks to UTF-8, I think there could be a bunch on those invisible chars that look like space...

Comment: @Haradzieniec The one in "hello world"? That's a non-breaking space.

Comment: What does `print_r(ord(' '));` output? replace the space with the char your experiencing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&thinsp;` or one of those below maybe?

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

```
<!-- General Punctuation -->
<!ENTITY ensp    CDATA "&#8194;" -- en space, U+2002 ISOpub -->
<!ENTITY emsp    CDATA "&#8195;" -- em space, U+2003 ISOpub -->
<!ENTITY thinsp  CDATA "&#8201;" -- thin space, U+2009 ISOpub -->
```

Answer (score 4):

no-break space  U+00A0  160
char(160) this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much:) From what I remember I found an applicable answer about 9 years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

in the old time of DOS, char 255 was a blank character

Comment: DOS 255 (decimal) is the no-break space, same as `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Unicode whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode), because there are plenty of them

Answer (score 1):

just echo your string contains whatever special characters using `rawurlencode()` function:

```
echo rawurlencode("whatever string with any \05 \02 weird symbols");
```

and see their codes preceded with % sign