# Javascript string() function returns correct value in IE, FF but not in chrome when used on amount = "$ 75.00 USD"

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome

I am currently having an issue that I cannot seem to work around.

```
var amount = "$ 75.00 USD";
```

I want only the 75.00 part. I tried with the following:

```
var new_str = amount.split(" ");
```

This gave me the following result in chrome:

0: "$ 75.00"
1: "USD"

So I found another work around:

```
var new_str = amount.substring(amount.indexOf(' '), 2).replace(',','');
```

this gives me 75.00 as I wanted in both Chrome and FF.

Problem is that in IE it gives me 0.

However, when I try out

```
var new_str = amount.split(" ");
```

in IE

0: "$"
1: "75.00"
2: "USD"

I am just trying to find one function that will work on both.. I could of course create an if statement but I am just thinking that split should be working..

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Best Seki

Comment: Use regex rather

Comment: If `amount.split(" ");` returns `["$ 75.00", "USD" ]` then the first "space" is not a regular space character.

Comment: `"$ 75.00 USD".split(" ")` in Chrome works as expected, splitting the string into three chunks. Looks as if you had something different than the space in your string. Maybe look there for possible answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319539/what-is-the-symbol-that-looks-like-space-but-not-a-space-not-a-nbsp

Comment: When I open up the console in Chrome and run your first example I get the string split in three parts as expected: `['$', '75.00', 'USD']`.

Comment: Same in Firefox (3 element array)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to *@mbojko* solution, but we look for **number - dot - number** pattern, rather than strip off not numbers values:

```js
const amount = "$ 75.00 USD $ 80.01 EUR";
const matches = amount.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g);

console.log(matches[0]);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

As you can see, it works also with multiple repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to filter out everything that isn't a digit or the decimal separator.

```js
const amount = "$ 75.00 USD";
const sanitizedAmount = amount.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

console.log(parseFloat(sanitizedAmount));
```

(Should work for all possible crazy characters in the string).